# Como subir mi aplicacion java hecha con el framework spring boot en la ide STS a CPANEL

Tags: spring-boot, cpanel

Quiero subir mi aplicacion java hecha con spring, thymeleaf a cpanel entonces estuve buscando como se hacia y pues entonces encontre que se tenia que exportar la aplicacion como war y dentro del cpanel creo una carpeta donde subo ese archivo war de alli cambio el .war a .zip y paso a descomprimir los archivos y al momento de hacer eso solo hay dos carpetas WEB-INF y META-INF donde estan todos mis archivos las clases que use y los archivos html css y js que use pero al momento de copiar el dominio en el navegador sale que la URL no se encontro en el servidor entonces alli esta mi problema no se como ejecutar en el cpanel mi aplicacion en mi local si funciona correctamente pero en el servidor nada alguien puede ayudarme.

En mi pom.xml tengo esto

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.capedu.proyecto-horario</groupId>
<artifactId>HorariosCapedu</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>HorariosCapedu</name>
<description>Generador de horarios</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```